# get result out of a pg-promise query

Tags: node.js, promise, pg-promise

I am working on a Node project with pg-promise. I need to fulfill a promise with the results of the query, but I can't get the results out.

```
get2 : function(id) {
    var qrm = pgp.queryResult;
    PG.db.any('SELECT * FROM referentiel_rd_client WHERE id=\'' + id + '\'')
        .then(data => {
            console.log('got query results');
            resolve(data);
        })
       .catch(error => {
           // error; 
        });
```

But the other promise (that should receive the data) never gets anything...
How do I get the results out of the query? (I can log them to the console).

Comment: You do not return anything from the function - do `return PG.db.any...` and in `then()` use `return data;`

Comment: Well, I added `return`, but other Promise still doesn't get anything.

Comment: Can you add the code responsible for calling the `get2` function?

Comment: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      M.get2(id, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
              return reject (err);
          }
      console.log('got success on promise with ' + data);
      resolve(data);
      
    });
  });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not create needless promises, it is an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)

---

- If you want to pre-process the result, in the end just return the result, 
  that's how promises work:

  ```
  get2: (id) => {
      return PG.db.any('SELECT * FROM referentiel_rd_client WHERE id=$1', id)
          .then(data => {
              console.log('got query results:', data);
              return data;
          });
  ```

---

- Never format queries manually, use the query formatting engine that comes with the library, or you will end up breaking queries.

---

Then you will call it like this:

```
get2(123)
    .then(data => {
        // success
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. How do you return the result as a distinct variable? You still cannot return from inside a `then`! So this is useless as an answer. What this design assumes is global variables or cache which you update asynchronously, but what about GraphQL resolvers, where you need to return an discrete value? What about if you want to do FP where you MUST return values without side-effects?

Comment: @BenjaminR I did answer the question, which had nothing to do with any distinct variable, rather not returning a promise. Can't return from inside a promise? You can and you do, and this solved the issue this guy had.

Comment: Dear chap, my apologies, it's my mistake, I misread the question. I will do a nominal edit to remove my downvote.

Comment: I guess I'm frustrated because there is a (**cough** Concurrency **cough**) gap where you can only return another `Promise`: `then(...)` returns a `Promise`. It's cool to *post*-process the result, but real code is messy and you may want to just save the value (not the promise!) to a variable. Returning from inside `then(...)` gives a value which needs another `then(...)` call to access, ad infinitum. My point was, _how & where does it stop?_ What if, when it's ready, I just want the value, alone, outside a Promise? Go, for example, deals with this this so trivially.